# How to validate JWT token in other project when you have separate project for Identity using asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt

I've two projects in solution. One is for Identity management using asp.net identity generating JWT tokens. In Second project there are API's that are secure and validating token that are generated from identity project but token validation not working.

I'm getting this error when calling api store route in postman. I'm passing token in Authorization header.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success:
>   404 (Not Found).
>   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
>
> IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is
>   hidden]'.
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string
>   address, CancellationToken cancel)
>
> InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration
>   from: '[PII is hidden]'.
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancel)
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers HttpRequestException: Response status code
>   does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
>   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string
>   address, CancellationToken cancel)
>
> Show raw exception details System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
>   Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String
>   address, CancellationToken cancel) IOException: IDX20804: Unable to
>   retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'.
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string
>   address, CancellationToken cancel)
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(string
>   address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancel)
>
> Show raw exception details System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to
>   retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'. --->
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not
>   indicate success: 404 (Not Found).    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String
>   address, CancellationToken cancel)    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String
>   address, CancellationToken cancel)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String
>   address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancel) InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain
>   configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'.
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancel)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext
>   context, string scheme)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>
> Show raw exception details System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803:
>   Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from:
>   '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response
>   status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String
>   address, CancellationToken cancel)    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String
>   address, CancellationToken cancel)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String
>   address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancel)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancel)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext
>   context, String scheme)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

This is my Startup.cs class in Identity project.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Cosmonaut;
using Cosmonaut.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Triverse.Identity.Models;
using Triverse.Identity.Services;
using IdentityRole = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDB.IdentityRole;

namespace Triverse.Identity
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            var endPointUri = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:EndpointUri");
            var primaryKey = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:PrimaryKey");
            var databaseId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:DatabaseId");
            var collectionId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:CollectionId");

            var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endPointUri), primaryKey);
            services.AddSingleton<IDocumentClient>(client);

            // make sure the database exists!
            var db = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(d => d.Id == databaseId).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()
                     ?? client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = databaseId }).Result;

            var databaseLink = db.SelfLink;

            services.AddIdentityWithDocumentDBStores<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
                dbOptions =>
                {
                    dbOptions.DocumentUrl = endPointUri;
                    dbOptions.DocumentKey = primaryKey;
                    dbOptions.DatabaseId = databaseId;
                    dbOptions.CollectionId = collectionId;
                },
                identityOptions =>
                {
                    identityOptions.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                });

            var cosmosSettings = new CosmosStoreSettings(databaseId, endPointUri, primaryKey);
            services.AddCosmosStore<ApplicationUser>(cosmosSettings);

            services.AddScoped<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<ITokenService, TokenService>();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Audience"],
                        IssuerSigningKey =
                            new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"])),
                        ValidateLifetime = true
                    };

                    cfg.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                        {
                            if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                            {
                                context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                                context.Response.Headers.Add("access-control-expose-headers", "Token-Expired");
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my appsettings.json in Identity project.

```
"Tokens": {
    "Key": "4343@!#ewewq",
    "Issuer": "http://localhost:44376/",
    "Audience": "http://localhost:44385/",
    "ExpiryMinutes": "55",
    "ValidateLifetime": true
  }
```

This is my Startup.cs class in Store project.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Cosmonaut;
using Cosmonaut.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Store.API.Services;

namespace Store.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            var endPointUri = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:EndpointUri");
            var primaryKey = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:PrimaryKey");
            var databaseId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:DatabaseId");

            var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endPointUri), primaryKey);
            services.AddSingleton<IDocumentClient>(client);

            var db = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(d => d.Id == databaseId).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()
                     ?? client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database {Id = databaseId}).Result;

            var databaseLink = db.SelfLink;

            var cosmosSettings = new CosmosStoreSettings(databaseId, endPointUri, primaryKey);
            services.AddCosmosStore<Models.Store>(cosmosSettings);

            services.AddScoped<IStoreRepository, StoreRepository>();

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:44376/";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Audience = "http://localhost:44385/";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my controller method in Store project.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetStores()
{
  var stores = new
  {
     Id = 1,
     Name = "T-Shirt",
     Price = "120.00"
  };

  return Ok(stores);
}
```

This is my JWT token generated from Identity project.

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzaGFAZG9tYWluLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6IjFjYjNkNjA2LWI4MGQtNGNlZC1hMWFjLThlYmUzNzc1ZGViOSIsIlVuaXF1ZUlkIjoiZjU1ZTM2MWQtYjFkYy00MDg4LTlmYjQtMDg3ZTI4OTFjNWI1IiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJzaGFAZG9tYWluLmNvbSIsImZpcnN0TmFtZSI6IlNoYXduIiwibmJmIjoxNTY0OTkwMjA1LCJleHAiOjE1NjQ5OTM1MDUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzNzYvIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0NDM4NS8ifQ.ZBK8Fi14QUc9ObZx7ojg7LPcl8Qs2vrQyhZi7Dbk4Gg
```

Comment: Your "Store" API is trying to internally call `http://localhost:44376/.well-known/openid-configuration` and the call is failing. You can enable `PII` logs with this `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;` - add it in your startup (remove it for prod).

Comment: How can i fix this? I'm using asp.net identity.

Comment: Are you hosting this locally? Enable PII first, and then you have to verify that the URL is accessible at least locally.

Comment: I've enable IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; this in startup class. URL is not accessible still. I'm not using identity servier, I'm using asp.net identity.

Comment: Try set `options.ValidateIssuer = false` in your Store project for `AddJwtBearer`

Comment: Currently it's hosting locally.

Comment: Setting options.ValidateIssuer = false still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: As @VidmantasBlazevicius mentions, your API code is trying to access http://localhost:44376/.well-known/openid-configuration to retrieve the well-known configuration - it's failing. First things first, can you access that URL in your browser, is that definitely where your IDentity service is running?

Comment: No i can't access this url 'localhost:44376/.well-known/openid-configuration'. I'm using asp.net Identity. I think this url is for identity server localhost:44376/.well-known/openid-configuration.

Comment: This url is part of general oauth2 spec, not just identity server. `AddJwtBearer` depends on this URL being published by the Identity Provider.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.NET Identity is not intended for this use case all by itself. You might want to look something like Identity Server which extends the functionality of Identity. It allows you to validate tokens in several ways,

1. It has an endpoint for validating tokens
2. It exposes a well known configuration endpoint that provide (along with a lot of other things) the public key of RSA certificate used to sign the token. So if you want, you can verify the signature yourself.

Comment: Is Identity Server support is by default in Asp.Net Core 3?

Comment: Identity Server 4 is a component that can be added to .net core.  I believe that it is already working with the 3.0 preview releases but I have not tried it myself. You can check it out here, https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4

Comment: Any alternatives to IS 4 now that they are starting to charge now? Or do you know if net 6 identity now supports this?